# Использование методов в родительском элементе

Tags: c#

У меня есть метод, в котором я храню и добавляю все Эвенты, выглядит он следующим образом:

```
internal class Calendar
{
    public List<Event>? EventsList = new List<Event>();
    private int[] date = { 24, 10, 2022 };
    public int this[int index] { 
        get { return date[index]; }
        set { date[index] = value; }
    }

    public List<Event> GetAllUpcoming()
    {
        List<Event> temp = new List<Event> ();
        foreach (var b in EventsList)
        {
            if (b.isUpcoming(b.start) == 1)
            {
                temp.Add(b);
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public void Add(Event A)
    {
        EventsList.Add(A);
    }
}
```

Далее сами методы выглядят примерно так:

```
internal class Event
    {
  

        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? start { get; set; }
        public string? end { get; set; }
    }
internal class Appointment : Event{
   public DateTime GetReminderTime()
   {
   return DateTime.Now
   }

}
```

И еще таких элементов несколько. Ключевой тут метод GetReminderTime(), когда я перебираю через foreach весь календарь, то мне он становится недоступен, так как его нет в родительском элементе, однако он абстрактный и в каждом другом классе, который наследуется от Event, такой метод есть. Как я могу вызвать эту функцию при переборе?

Comment: Вы сами себе ответили: `Как я могу вызвать эту функцию при переборе?` -> `его нет в родительском элементе`. Очевидно вроде, что надо значит его добавить родителю? Без разницы что у потомков, если вы все обобщаете, делаете некий единый "интерфейс" работы с вашими классами, то вы обязаны в том классе, от которого наследуетесь сделать все "обобщенное". Если вам в этом классе не нужен данный метод, то значит у вас не так с проектированием, делайте значит отдельно просто интерфейс (не класс) и наследуйте `Appointment` от него, минуя `Event`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вообще, в моем задании не прописана реализация метода в Event, поэтому я не стал так делать. И еще, я пытался подобное осуществить, но почему-то всегда вызывался родительский метод, пробовал через New

Comment: `не прописана реализация метода` - не следуйте слепо заданию, у вас общая логика, которая объединена одним конкретным классом, вот там эту общую логику и пишите. `всегда вызывался родительский метод` - наверно потому, что у вас нет "абстрактного" как вы говорите, у вас простые классы, без какого-либо переопределения.

Comment: У вас должно быть что-то по типу `abstract class Event { public virtual DateTime GetReminderTime(){ ... } }`, далее `class Appointment : Event { public override DateTime GetReminderTime() { ... } }`. `abstract` - это значит "можем только наследовать", сделать `new()` не сможете. `virtual` - это значит "данный объект можно переопределить". Если в `Event` классе не нужна логика, а нужно просто чтоб был метод, то делайте его тоже `abstract`. А вообще, если у вас нет общей логики, только структура, то для этого используют интерфейсы.